# MySQL Workbench Synchronizing Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is more of an annoyance for me...so I was hoping someone could tell me how to make it go away.

I am using MySQL Workbench to keep a model of my database.  Whenever I "Synchronize with any Source", the program always syncs my stored procedures.  Even if there is only 1 change to a table, all the stored procedures get dropped and recreated.

My model is on a Win 10 computer w/ MySQL Workbench 6.3.  It is synchronizing with a Win 7 "server" w/ MySQL Server 5.5.

Can anyone tell me how to make workbench properly detect SP changes and only sync when a change is made?  Tables and views work properly...SPs do not.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Have you tried with a new/different model? Could be this is a bug. If so, file a bug report (http://bugs.mysql.com).

Comment: Workbench is up to date according to the "Check for Updates" menu option.  MySQL is 5.5, so not the most recent...But this has been happening ever since I was first given the task of maintaining this database in January 2016.  At first I didn't care, because there were so many issues with the DB that this was the least of my worries...now, it is just taking too long for a simple sync operation.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by skip synchronization of stored procedure and functions, you can check that checkbox when synchronized model.

Here's a screenshot:

[Checkbox about synchronize stored procedure and functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z259.png)